# Mocking __mul__ and __rmul__ in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am attempting to mock the following line of code:

```
surface['width'] = '{:~}'.format(self._width * self._scaling_factor_x)
```

I pass _width and _scaling_factor_x as objects of class unittest.MagicMock. Afterwards, I replace the __mul__ method of _width with:

```
def multiplicateMocks(self, other):
    return MagicMock(name = self.name + '*' + other.name)
```

This code, however, does not work. The second argument, `other`, is not passed.
Testing in a Python interpreter session shows that having replaced __mul__ with:

```
def newMul(*args):
    return args
```

and calling it, there is indeed only a single argument present - the lefthand operand.

Can a proper multiplication be attempted?

Update: fleshing out the issue.

a) standard MagicMock behaviour:

```
In [61]: mock1 = MagicMock(name="mock1")
In [62]: mock2 = MagicMock(name="mock2")
In [63]: mock1*mock2
Out[63]: <MagicMock name='mock.__mul__()' id='73472880'>
```

b) the intended result of substituting `**mul**:

```
In [63]: mock1*mock2
Out[63]: <MagicMock name='mock1*mock2' id='73472880'>
```

c) **mul** replacement:

```
def multiplicateMocks(self, other):
    return MagicMock(name = self.name + '*' + other.name)
```

d) erroneous result:

```
In [75]: mock1.__mul__.side_effect = multiplicateMocks

In [76]: mock1*mock2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-36051f78b408> in <module>()
----> 1 mock1*mock2

c:\users\redacted\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\unittest\mock.py i
n __call__(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs)
    915         # in the signature
    916         _mock_self._mock_check_sig(*args, **kwargs)
--> 917         return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
    918
    919

c:\users\redacted\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\unittest\mock.py i
n _mock_call(_mock_self, *args, **kwargs)
    981                 return result
    982
--> 983             ret_val = effect(*args, **kwargs)
    984
    985         if (self._mock_wraps is not None and

TypeError: multiplicateMocks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please update your question with a short reproductible example of the problem and add the full error message you get ?

Comment: Please give a [mcve], it's not at all clear what you're testing, how, or why you expected that mock to do anything useful.

Comment: The original post has been expanded upon. 

I am testing the class and want to make sure that this multiplication is indeed taking place. I could dodge the issue by passing in numbers and checking the product of their multiplication. However, I would like to know how to resolve the issue using mock objects.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, setting `__mul__` on an instance instead of a class wouldn't work at all, but `Mock` and `MagicMock` let you do it. The thing is, `mock1.__mul__` is a *bound method*, or at least it's supposed to behave like one. That means it gets called like

```
mock1.__mul__(mock2)
```

not `mock1.__mul__(mock1, mock2)`.

You've written your `multiplicateMocks` to behave as an unbound method. You need to bind it:

```
mock1.__mul__.side_effect = multiplicateMocks.__get__(mock1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the pre-existing magic methods in MagicMock are interfering with your attempts to override them.

You might have better luck by using a standard Mock instead....

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock1 = Mock(name="mock1")
mock2 = Mock(name="mock2")

def multiplicateMocks(self, other):
    mock_name = str(self.name) + '*' + str(other.name)
    return Mock(name=mock_name)

mock1.__mul__ = multiplicateMocks

mock1*mock2
```

resulting string returned is

```
<Mock name="<Mock name='mock1.name' id='2175954027520'>*<Mock name='mock2.name' id='2175954027856'>" id='2175954027464'>
```